# Offline Firefox performance tool

Tags: firefox, performance-testing, firefox-developer-tools

I have some performance issue in an web app developped on a secured enterprised network. Internet connection is not available.
And since some version of Firefox, the performance tool send me to something like "https://profiler.firefox.com/from-browser" that, of course, is not accessible.

How can I analyse performance issue with no internet connection ? (Offline tool or an anlternative to firefox performance tool ?)